# How to determine if a complement is a predicative complement or a locative complement?

Tags: complements, predicative-complements

> (1) *She is **out** and will be back in soon.*
>
> (2) *She is **out** and will be conscious soon.*

Is ***out*** a locative complement in (1) but a predicative complement in (2)?

If so, is the distinction between the two complements purely semantic?

Is there any reliable way to distinguish the two kinds of complements?

Comment: 'Come around' has a directional reading too!

Comment: Doesn't the answer lie that out has more than one meaning: 1. out (to be outside) 2. out (to be knocked out=senseless) 3. out (to be freed from jail) *After seven months, she is out.*

Comment: Indeed it's semantic. We need no other way. Btw, show some background research, too. Good Luck.